# Create + execute virtual bash script

Tags: macos, bash, unix

Is there a way to create and execute a virtual bash script instead of writing out the script to the filesystem and then executing the .sh file with `bash`?

I am using Node.js and there may be libraries to construct and execute a bash script; I guess I am wondering how that is done without saving a file somewhere.

Comment: A very interesting question, but I guess that it will be hard to do. Do you still intend to use /bin/bash as the interpreter?

Comment: yeah, I would be using bash to run the script. The reason I ask is because this is just a temporary file that will get overwritten because the content is dynamic, basically a list of sequential tasks. So there is no need to save the file to the filesystem if I can avoid cluttering it.

Comment: added an answer, let me know if you think it's sane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done like so:

```
echo 'echo hi' | bash
```

pretty convenient actually, because you don't need to write files out to the filesystem; no need to create a .sh file and run it and then delete the file after the run.

To use with Node.js, you would run it like so:

```
 const cp = require('child_process');

 const bashCmd  = 'echo "echo hello world" | bash';

 cp.exec(bashCmd, function (err, stdout, stderr) {

        if (err) {
            console.error(err.stack);
        }

        console.log(stdout);
        console.error(stderr);

        process.exit(0);


    });
```

Currently I am using this to generate Istanbul coverage reports for our tests. The following code:

```
   var bash = 'echo "';

    const $files = sumanUtils.removeSharedRootPath(files);

    $files.forEach(function (file) {

        bash += 'istanbul cover ' + file[0] + ' --dir ./coverage/' + String(file[1]).replace(/\//g,'-') + '\n';

    });

    bash += 'istanbul report" | bash';

    console.log(bash);


    cp.exec(bash, function (err, stdout, stderr) {

        if (err) {
            console.error(err.stack);
            process.exit(1);
        }

        console.log(stdout);
        console.error(stderr);

        process.exit(0);


    });
```

generates a bash command that looks like this:

```
echo "istanbul cover /Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman/test/build-tests/empty.js --dir ./coverage/empty.js
istanbul cover /Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman/test/build-tests/test6.js --dir ./coverage/test6.js
istanbul cover /Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman/test/build-tests/test7-start.js --dir ./coverage/test7-start.js
istanbul cover /Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman/test/build-tests/test8.js --dir ./coverage/test8.js
istanbul cover /Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman/test/build-tests/test9.js --dir ./coverage/test9.js
istanbul report" | bash
```

Comment: Why don't you *try* it? Posting untested speculation as an answer is not helpful.

Comment: That is great, and it looks easier than I expected. But can you take the output from Node.js and connect it to stdin of bash? Can you let Node.js generate the `echo hi`?

Comment: yes, you can, will post the full answer, you use child_process.exec. I am a bit bemused by the downvotes. Also I  wonder if you can just use "sudo bash 'your shell command here'"